# The relationship between analytic and $C^\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

We have a function $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ defined as $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),...,f_m(x))$ that for every $i$, $f_i:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^\infty$ function if every partial differential of $f_i$ is differentiable of every order in every points of $U$.

Now my question is:

a) Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be open and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ analytic, Prove that $f$ is $C^\infty$.

So, what is the relationship between analytic and $C^\infty$ is this question?

How can I prove (a)?

Comment: Analytic means that at every point $a\in U$ there is an open set $V\subset U$ with $a\in V$ and a power series $\sum_na_n(x-a)^n$ that converges in all of $V$ to $f$. In particular, it will converge uniformly on compact subsets of $V$. From that you can deduce that $f$ is $C^\infty$, since the power series is $C^\infty$. I would add a second part to the problem to show that there are $C^\infty$ functions that are not analytic. Like $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1126895/29335

Comment: You prove (a) like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula). Note that this proves $f$ is $C^\infty$ under complex differentiation. You will need to then show that complex $C^\infty$ implies the $C^\infty$ as defined here.

Comment: @conditionalMethod This would be worth to be an official answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost No one stops you. Go.